# Crashlytics exception on initialize

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm having the following exception when intializng crashlytics native on an android application

```
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:43)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.finalizeNativeReport(CrashlyticsController.java:967)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:346)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:45)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
--
--
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.NativeFileUtils.filter(NativeFileUtils.java:43)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.NativeFileUtils.minidumpFromDirectory(NativeFileUtils.java:53)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.finalizeMostRecentNativeCrash(CrashlyticsController.java:903)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$1700(CrashlyticsController.java:69)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$16.call(CrashlyticsController.java:977)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$16.call(CrashlyticsController.java:967)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
--
--
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
12-12 10:55:54.104 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   ... 1 more
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics encountered a problem during asynchronous initialization.
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.finalizeNativeReport(CrashlyticsController.java:967)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:346)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.doInBackground(CrashlyticsCore.java:45)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-12 10:55:54.124 15540 15621 E CrashlyticsCore:   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
```

my configuration is the following:

on Application.java

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
        .kits(new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())
        .debuggable(true)
        .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

on build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    // If using the Android plugin for Gradle version 2.2.0+ with the externalNativeBuild DSL,
    // you should remove the androidNdkOut and androidNdkLibsOut properties, as these paths will
    // automatically be detected by the Fabric plugin.
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
    manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

I try to cause a crash like this on my native code :

```
throw std::runtime_error {"Please crash"} ;
```

the crash is happening many times and native crash are not reported.

PS: I'm using crashlytics 2.9.6 and crashlytics_ndk 2.0.5.
PSS: Java crashs are working perfectly.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure if you have correct versions from [crashlytics-ndk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports) instructions.

on 02.14.2019:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.0'
```

Also firebase [initialize automatically](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html) with a help of content providers!
So you should remove Fabric initialization from code!